# Is there a way to make Crashplan make smaller backup files.. so I can use Skydrive as cloud backup?

Tags: onedrive, crashplan

Title basically says it all; Right now Crashplan makes backup files that are much bigger than the filesize that Skydrive allows. Does anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to look and what Crashplan is backing up and then see if you can exclude certain file extensions or folders.

I would use WinDirStat to analyse the folders and then look at the list of extensions sorted by size to see if any of them can be ignored.

In my case, things like GCF (Steam files, easily re-downloadable), EXE/OCX/DLL (since you'll have to re-install your apps if you rebuilt your PC anyway) and TMP are sizeable ones that can be safely ignored.

Answer (score -1):

SkyDrive now supports files with the size up to 2GB. In my point it is enough for backup solution.